# Hive Insert Overwrite to HBase not working

Tags: java, hive, hbase

Hive 'insert overwrite table' seems not to be working properly.

I have the following `Hive` query:

```
from my_input_table
  insert into      table my_output_table     where ...
  insert overwrite table my_output_table_tmp where ...
```

The inserts statements above are identical if not for the table name. Both `my_output_table` and `my_output_table_tmp` are `HBase` tables. It looks like the second insert (overwrite) is not working properly as data keeps getting added to the table (the content is never replaced). The content of my_output_table and my_output_table_tmp are identical even after 2 or more iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is expected behavior. I also experienced the same thing.
If you create a hive table in Hbase using Hbase storage handler you cannot perform INSERT OVERWRITE. It doesnt throw any exception but at the same time it doesnt delete the existing records. rather it simply puts the new records.

So in a way INSERT and INSERT OVERWRITE  works alike.

One more thing, you cannot even truncate the table from hive.

```
hive> truncate table hbase_table_1;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10147]: Cannot truncate non-native table hbase_table_1.
```

But delete/update operation you can do from Hbase side. It will be reflected in hive.